# Extracting Particular lines in a text file

Tags: python, file, csv, text

> I have a text file and I want to extract only certain lines in this file I put it in another file

```
for line in cFicIn:

fieldwidths = (22, 22, 22)  # negative widths represent ignored padding fields
parse = make_parser(fieldwidths)
fields = parse(line)
```

I have three columns in the text file. fields[0] give the columns 0....

```
Frequency [Hz]           Peak amplitude           Phase [degrees]
117.131422636205         1528954.28753915         -54.0642640720085
234.26284527241          1051596.71706853         -6.8190622364283
351.302901744313         456787.344479019         47.6494383764102
Peak interpolation: Numeric
```

However me I want to recover the data that is between the two lines in the file knowing I have several.The line Frequency and Peak interpolation

```
if 'Frequency' and 'Phase' in line   :


       newline=(str(a)+';'+fields[0].strip()+';'+fields[1].strip()+';'+fields[2].strip()+';'+'\n')
       newline.replace(" ","")
       a=a+1
       print(newline)



       csv_file.write(newline)

       csv_file.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a bool variable called like *should_process_line* and process line iff this variable is True. Set it to True after you encounter 'Frequency' and 'Phase', set it to False after you encounter 'Peak interpolation'.
While we're at it, your newline generation could be rewritten as

```
newline = str(a) + ';'.join([x.strip() for x in fields])
```

The way it is in the question, your newline variable is not an str, but actually a tuple whose only element is a string you want. Also, adding '\n' in the end will be unnecessary, if you use

```
print(newline, file=csv_file)
```

print adds '\n' to the end of everything it prints anyway.

Comment: thank you .you say `for line in infile:
        if line.strip() == "Start":
            copy = True
        elif line.strip() == "End":
            copy = False
        elif copy:
            outfile.write(line)
`

Comment: Not elif, in the last case it should be if.